# How to correctly retrieve Unicode text from a control?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

Here is an example of Unicode: I avoided to use a win32 application for for brevity sake:

In main I created an `edit` control, a `button` to retrieve text from it and adds it to the `listbox` when pressed. So I used an object of `struct MSG` and blocked in a while loop `peeking` the messages from the message queue.

```
int main(){

    // An edit control where I can add any unicode text to.
    HWND hEdit = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 
        L"Edit", L"你好！ 你好吗？", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU,
        200, 100, 250, 70, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    // A listobx to receive the content of the edit control when pressing the button get text.
    HWND hLstBx = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"Listbox", NULL, WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        500, 100, 170, 400, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    // A button when pressed adds the content of the edit to the listbox.
    HWND hGetText = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"Button", L"中文", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE,
        450, 300, 100, 70, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);


    // msg struct to pass to GetMessage to receive the messages from the queue.
    MSG msg;


    // blocking and getting messages from the queue.
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        // some virtual keys translation.
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        // sending the message to the specified window.
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);

        // Now after the messages sent to the target Window I check which control the message has been passed to, So if it is the button then:
        if (msg.message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && 
            msg.hwnd == hGetText) {
            std::wstring wstrBuff;

            int txtLen = SendMessageW(hEdit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
        //  SendMessageW(hEdit, WM_GETTEXT, txtLen + 1, (LPARAM)wstrBuff.c_str());
        //  MessageBoxW(0, wstrBuff.c_str(), 0, 0);


            wchar_t lpTxt[MAX_PATH];
            SendMessageW(hEdit, WM_GETTEXT, MAX_PATH, (LPARAM)lpTxt);
            SendMessageW(hLstBx, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)lpTxt);
            MessageBoxW(0, lpTxt, L"你好！ 你好吗？", 0);
            //delete[]lpTxt;
        }
    }

    std::wcout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::wcin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Every thing works fine except: If I un-comment the lines above I get run-time error facing the assertion message showing me the `txtLen` and the size of the text of the edit control. Is this because there's some string overlapping?

If I enter a small text it works fine but with a text about 14 characters I get the error.

- Also is that the right way to pass `std::wstring.c_str()` to `SendMessageW()` to get the text?
- One last question: How to correctly and effectively retrieve Unicode text from a control? How to use `LPWSTR` with dynamic memory: I don't want to exhaust stack.
- NB: I saved the source file as `utf8 /BOM` otherwise I get unreadable characters. Thanks to the members who helped me about that.

Comment: @Ron: I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ron: No it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You don't need to delete the `lpTxt` array because it is not dynamically allocated with `new`

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT: Yes that was from the previous example before using class `wstring`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending `(LPARAM)wstrBuff.c_str()` will return a pointer to read-only buffer with a single null symbol, not a buffer of `txtLen + 1` symbols. If you are using latest VS (with C++17 standard support) you can modify your code to supply a proper pointer:

```
 std::wstring wstrBuff;
 wstrBuff.resize(txtLen + 1);
 const LRESULT copied_symbols_count = SendMessageW
 (
     hEdit
 ,   WM_GETTEXT
 ,   static_cast<WPARAM>(wstrBuff.size())
 ,   reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(wstrBuff.data())
 );
 if(copied_symbols_count == txtLen)
 {
     assert(L'\0' == wstrBuff.back());
     wstrBuff.pop_back(); // get rid of terminating null
 }
 else
 {
     wstrBuff.clear(); // something went wrong...
 }
```

Note that C++17 standard adds non-const-qualified `wstring::data()` method that can be safely used to obtain a pointer to writable buffer.

Comment: So it is wrong? Thanks. But if you don't mind answer the remaining questions.

Comment: Note also that the change to `data()` was made in the standard because all the compilers already returned a writable pointer simply cast to `const`. So if you `const_cast` the returned value from `data()` it's likely to work in older compilers too, even though it's technically undefined behavior. But the safe way to do it is `&wstrbuff[0]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom The "safe way" of `&wstrBuff[0]` is only safe from C++11 on. Before that it was not guaranteed by standard, that the characters are stored in a contiguous chunk of memory that is terminated by a null character.

Comment: @zett42 of course you're right, I shouldn't have made that edit.